# .one() is not calling other same live components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery `.one()` code:

```
$("<div class='one'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");
$("<div class='one'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");
$("<div class='one'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");

$("#mane").one("click", ".one", function(event){
     alert(1);
});
```

**Why is it called once? And not once per item?** In the documentation [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function is called once per item?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74cv9/

Thanks.

Comment: You only have **one item** - `#mane`. That's where the event is bound to

Comment: Cause it's delegated to the #name element.

Comment: there is only one event bound, to one element. That one event can only happen once.

Comment: @j08691 - yes it does!

Comment: @j08691 Yeah it does, but it doesn't do what the OP expects - it still allows the callback to execute only once

Comment: @j08691 yes, though the way it works proves to be confusing.

Comment: I guess you have to keep track yourself whether any of elements was clicked or not. Not difficult with jQuery's `.data` method.

Comment: I don't even know why I asked that. Ug, TGIF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this functionality is built in, so you'll have to do it yourself:

```
$("#mane").on("click", ".one", function(event){
    if ( !$(this).data('clicked') ) {

        // do your stuff here, this .one element hasn't been clicked before



        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's seems that it should be build in ? Should this be mention to the jQuery team or do you think they are aware of it?

Comment: @Jessica Why should it be built in? It doesn't make sense to. The way `.one()` works with your code **makes sense** - only execute the handler once for any descendant `.one` clicked. You bound the event to `#mane`. Clicking anywhere inside of `#mane` causes the event to bubble. The handler will execute **once** only if the event originated from a `.one` descendant. Look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bQ2wG/ . Notice how clicking the `.two` element does nothing.

Comment: @Ian one() doesn't make much sense for delegated events with it's current functionality.

Comment: @Jessica That's fine if you don't understand it. It works as it's supposed to. If you want it to work differently, you can use adeneo's code or make your own plugin that does something **different than** `.one()` delegation

Comment: @Jessica For example, this *could* be used: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj3V7/ . It only works for the specific parameters `events, selector, handler` (which is what you are using), and is just an example

Answer (score 1):

The event is bound to a single element `#mane` and therefore will only happen to that element once, regardless of how many elements you delegate it to. An easy way around this is to use `.on` instead and an additional selector whether it be a class, attribute, etc, something that can be removed/changed after the event happens:

```
$("<div class='one clickable'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");
$("<div class='one clickable'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");
$("<div class='one clickable'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");

$("#mane").on("click", ".one.clickable", function(event){
     alert(1);
     $(this).removeClass("clickable");
});
```

Comment: but wont it mean that the click event is fired every time '.one' is clicked? Seems an incorrect solution to me

Comment: @MandeepJain a click event is fired regardless, however we're changing whether or not we catch the event. In this case, we will only catch the event once per `.one` element.

Comment: @MandeepJain As soon as the `clickable` class is removed (which happens when it's first clicked), the handler won't execute for that `.one` element.

Comment: but using .one() i think jquery itself unbinds the event after executing it once, right? So why fire unnecessary calls ?

Comment: @MandeepJain because .one will unbind itself too early in this case. in my opinion .one doesn't make much sense for delegated events with it's current functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Because according to your code, you are binding the one event to '#mane" and not to '.one'.

It should be like this

```
$(".one").one("click", function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: dont understand why this was downvoted? If you find this incorrect ,feel free to comment. Dont be a coward and keep on downvoting unnecessarily :)

Comment: Because you didn't read the question - the OP is using event delegation with `.on()`, so that the event will fire once for any descendant `.one` element. Using your method (like the several other wrong answers) will only bind the event to elements that exist when the binding occurs. The point is that this doesn't work for dynamic `.one` elements which is what the OP needs

Comment: Hmm since it is not specifically mentioned that event delegation is needed to be used, most of them(the wrong answers according to you) have a different approach :) Anyways, thanks for making it clear :)

Comment: If the OP is **using** event delegation, and has commented on other answers saying something like "this won't work for live elements", then I'd say they "need" it.

Answer (score -2):

Here's updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74cv9/2/

And the code:

```
$("#mane").find('.one').one("click", function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

The jQuery documentation states that:

> the event handler is called once for each event type

not once per selector. And in your initial code there's only one event, 'click'.

Feel free to challenge my answer :)

Comment: The elements have to exist at the moment you bind the event handler, which does not seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: This is not live, add another '$("<div class='one'>One</div>").appendTo("#mane");' bellow the action listener and this will fail.

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
$("#mane").on("click", ".one", function(event){
  alert(1);
  $(this).off(event);
});
```

Comment: `$this` is not defined, and `.off()` accepts a string (event name) and an optional function reference, not an `Event` object

Comment: Missed the brackets around this. As for `off()` according to the documentation for `one()`, that syntax is perfectly valid.

Comment: You're right. I think @adeneo's way might be the way to go. For the record, for the argument to `off`, from the docs: As with .on(), you can pass events as an object instead of specifying an events string and handler function as separate arguments.

Comment: @RuyDiaz What they mean by that is that you can just pass something like this: `{click: function () {}, change: function () {}}`

Comment: You could give the event handler a name and then do `$(this).off(funcName)`. Or use namespaced events. This is a good start, but it does not work the way you posted it.

Comment: @Ian unfortunately I can't link to the specific section of the doc, but take a look at the last code snippet right _before_ the "Examples:" heading in http://api.jquery.com/one/. The one prefaced with "This code is equivalent to:"

Comment: @RuyDiaz Oh I saw that after you said it (but I've never seen it being used that way and isn't documented, so I'm not exactly sure how that works). My last comment was a reply to you saying `As with .on(), you can pass events as an object instead of specifying an events string and handler function as separate arguments.`. What that text means is instead of having to do `.on("click", clickHandler).on("change", changeHandler)`, you can use `.on({click: clickHandler, change: changeHandler})`